# Unable to play sound in Google Chrome using a MediaStreamAudioSourceNode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I've been toying with WebRTC but I'm completely unable to play a simple audio stream after properly granting rights to the browser to use the input device.

I just try to connect the input device to the context destination, but it doesn't work.

This snippet isn't working and I think it should:

```
function success(stream)
{
    var audioContext      = new webkitAudioContext();
    var mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    mediaStreamSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
}

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true, video:false}, success);
```

This doesn't seem to capture any sound from my working microphone, but if I use a simple  tag and create a blob url the code suddenly starts working.

```
function success(stream)
{
    audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    audio.play();
}

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true, video:false}, success);
```

Also, not a single of these demos seems to be working for me: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/.

Fiddle for the first snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/AvMtt/

Fiddle for the second snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/vxeDg/

Using Chrome 28.0.1500.71 beta-m on Windows 7x64.

I have a single input device, and two output devices (speakers, headsets). Every device is using the same sample rate.

Comment: Not much help, but they both work for me.

Comment: @bbs that was really helpful to be honest, at least now I know that there's something wrong with webrtc and my configuration. Would you please tell me which OS, chrome version and audio device configuration are you using?

Comment: OS Windows 8  27.0.1453.116 m, noticed I could update to 28.0.1500.71 m  in which they also both work. I have a windows 8 x64 pc, internal audio device, connected to headphone out, but also works on device speakers.

Comment: i same issue a month ago and i solve this issue successfully.

step:  1. go to "Realtek HD Audio Manager".
       2. selct "Speakers tab" and after select "Default Format tab" and set "Default Format : 24Bits, 96000 Hz (Studio Quality)".
       3. selct "Macrophone tab" and after select "Default Format tab" and set "Default Format : 16Bits, 96000 Hz (Studio Quality)".
       4. give "ok"
       5. now working

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost 6 years old, but for anyone who stumbles across it, the modern version of this looks something like:

```
function success(stream) {
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    mediaStreamSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(success)
.catch((e) => {
    console.dir(e);
});
```

And appears to work based on https://jsfiddle.net/jmcker/g3j1yo85